# Postman unauthorized

Tags: api, .net-core, iis, postman, certificate

Postman unauthorized unable to verify the first certificate

I was making an api in .net core, Postman worked fine before, when I finished, it just gave me this error.

The controller

```
 //[AllowAnonymous]
    //[ApiController]
    [Route("api/person")]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {
            
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

        public PersonController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
     
        [HttpGet("GetAllPersons")]
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons()
        {
            return unitOfWork.Person.GetAll();
        }

        [HttpPost("AddPerson")]
        public void AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            unitOfWork.Person.Add(person);
        }
        
        [HttpGet("GetAdultPersons")]
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAdultPersons()
        {
            return unitOfWork.Person.GetAdultPersons();
        }
    }
```

startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<PeopleContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"))
            );
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    //.AllowCredentials()
                    );
            });

            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseAuthentication();
            //app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

I reinstalled postman and IIS.

I also comment:
//app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();

//[AllowAnonymous]
//[ApiController]

On Postman:
Settings > general > SSL Certificate Verification > off
Certificates > CA certificates > off

I'm not using any header, postman seems to add some as default

Postman suggest this:
No authentication protocol has been selected in IIS (not even anonymous).

Only integrated authentication is allowed, and a client browser that does not support integrated authentication was used.

Integrated authentication is enabled and the request was sent through a proxy server that changed the authentication headers before they reached the web server.

The web server is not configured for access anonymous and a required authorization header was not received.

The configuration section "configuration/system.webServer/authorization" may be cleanly denying access to the user.

Comment: Did you troubleshoot as Postman suggested? Try to enable anonymous authentication in IIS and configure your web server to allow anonymous access, you can check authorization settings in web.config file or through IIS configuration.